# Download file from Django Project root using a button

Tags: python, django, excel, csv, reddit

So, this is the webpage I'm creating atm with Django 1.8:
[image]

***Want the user to be able to export the data as .csv.***

*When the user:*

1. writes a subreddit name in the box
2. presses the button 'Get Data'

*What happens:*

1. it's created a test.csv (saved in the root of the project)
2. data is retrieved using Praw
3. data is inserted into the .csv
4. data is rendered for the users to see

**The problem now is:**
I want the button with 'Export to Excel', to download the generated file from the root of the Django project.

This is for the button:

```
 <form class="export_excel" id="login_form" action="/app/export">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" value="Export to Excel" type="submit">Export To Excel</button>
 </form>
```

This is in `app/views.py`:

```
def export(request):

    filename = "test.csv" # this is the file people must download

    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=' + filename
    response['Content-Type'] = 'application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-16'
    return response
```

This is in `app/urls.py`:

```
# app/urls.py
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

# Create your urls here.
urlpatterns = [
(...)
  url(r'^export/$', views.export, name='export')
]
```

This is the error I'm getting when clicking the button:
[image]

**Question is:** How can I make the user export the file using the button? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for your help / guidance

**Handy links:**

[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41711536/exporting-django-objects-model-in-csv)

[Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20040965/how-to-export-data-in-python-with-excel-format)

[Link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37012924/python-object-does-not-support-item-assignment)

[Link 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8542343/object-does-not-support-item-assignment-error)

Comment: I don't know about the reddit stuff, but this approach seems awfully complicated, why are you saving the generated file? Have looked at examples like this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5146539/streaming-a-csv-file-in-django were the .csv is created and directly sent to the user (or even streamed for larger files)?

Comment: It was the only solution I could think of.
No, thank you for sharing. I'm going to look now @andipla

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must first create the `response` object in order to assign headers to it.

```
def export(request):
    filename = "test.csv" # this is the file people must download
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        response = HttpResponse(f.read(), content_type='application/vnd.ms-excel')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=' + filename
        response['Content-Type'] = 'application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-16'
        return response
```

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36392510/django-download-a-file)

Comment: Great, it's downloading.
Still, this is downloading the code of the page where this button is at, without the area with the data. I just wanted the data part, that's why mentioned to get the file that was already in the server

Comment: thank you, this works fine. Just do a little edit to `response = HttpResponse(f.read(), content_type='application/vnd.ms-excel')`, you have an extra 'h'